# SQLAlchemy inheritance relations issue

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

My SQLAlchemy model has a base class `Alpha` and two derived classes `Beta` and `Gamma`. `Beta` is also a field of `Beta`. My implementation results in the message error below. How do I fix this join condition issue?

> AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between
> parent/child tables on relationship Beta.gammas - there are multiple
> foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys'
> argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as
> containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

```py
class Alpha(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = 'alpha'

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Integer)
    type_ = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "alpha",
        "polymorphic_on": type_,
    }

class Beta(Alpha):
    __tablename__ = 'beta'

    id_ = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('alpha.id_'), primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(Integer)

    # Related
    gammas = relationship('Gamma', back_populates='beta')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": 'beta',
    }

class Gamma(Alpha):
    __tablename__ = 'gamma'

    id_ = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('alpha.id_'), primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(Integer)

    beta_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('beta.id_'))
    beta = relationship('Beta', back_populates='gammas')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": 'gamma',
    }

declarative_base().metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
beta = Beta()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing two lines:

1. `gammas = relationship('Gamma', back_populates='beta', foreign_keys='Gamma.beta_id')`
2. `beta = relationship('Beta', back_populates='gammas', foreign_keys=[beta_id])`

Thus, the complete new code becomes:

```py
class Alpha(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = 'alpha'

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Integer)
    type_ = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "alpha",
        "polymorphic_on": type_,
    }

class Beta(Alpha):
    __tablename__ = 'beta'

    id_ = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('alpha.id_'), primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(Integer)

    # Related
    gammas = relationship('Gamma', back_populates='beta', foreign_keys='Gamma.beta_id')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": 'beta',
    }

class Gamma(Alpha):
    __tablename__ = 'gamma'

    id_ = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('alpha.id_'), primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(Integer)

    beta_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('beta.id_'))
    beta = relationship('Beta', back_populates='gammas', foreign_keys=[beta_id])

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": 'gamma',
    }

declarative_base().metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
beta = Beta()
```

More information in https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths.